# PHP Regex Any Character

Tags: php, regex

The `.` character in a php regex accepts all characters, except a newline. What can I use to accept ALL characters, including newlines?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is commonly used to capture all characters:

```
[\s\S]
```

You could use any other combination of "Type-X + Non-Type-X" in the same way:

```
[\d\D]
[\w\W]
```

but `[\s\S]` is recognized by convention as a shorthand for "really anything".

You can also use the `.` if you switch the regex into "dotall" (a.k.a. "single-line") mode via the `"s"` modifier. Sometimes that's not a viable solution (dynamic regex in a black box, for example, or if you don't want to modify the *entire* regex). In such cases the other alternatives do the same, no matter how the regex is configured.

Comment: And why would you think that?

Comment: Testing on http://regex101.com/. It says the regex is any single space or non-space. Looks like (.*?) will allow any combination of characters (but still not newlines).

Comment: Of course you'd have to add a multiplier of your choice. "any character" was the question, after all.

Answer (score 11):

It's the the `.` character that means "every character" (**edit**: OP edited). And you need to add the option s to your regexp, for example :

```
preg_match("`(.+)`s", "\n");
```

Comment: Aren't there supposed to be forward slashes at the beginning and end of a regexp?

Comment: Can be, but any pair of delimiters will do.

Comment: Not in PHP. It has to start and end with a delimiter (you can choose it), and every character past the last delimiter is an option (i.e. U for ungreedy, i for case-insensitive, etc.)

Comment: +1 Depending on your needs `m` is an option as well. But based on the OP, `s` is the way to go.

Comment: Someone should explain `s` (and perhaps `m`) to make this really complete.

Comment: `/m` makes `^` and `$` apply to each line (instead of full string), `/s` makes `.` also match `\n`, and `/ms` applies both (check each line and full string). See [PHP manual regarding modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) and [Perl RegEx manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) (which PHP's preg_match is based on).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>would</strike>

```
[.\n]+
```

not work?

How about `(.|\n)+`? I tested it and it seems to work.

I am quite sure this is the literal interpretation of exactly what you were asking for.

Comment: The `.` in a character class does not mean "any character". It means "a dot". Character classes have their own syntax. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks for the explanation, I just realized it now. I guess I should test my answers before I post them. I've edited my answer now.

Comment: Common error. I see people do `[this|that|\d]` a lot, when they really mean `(this|that|\d)`. *P.S.: `(.|\n)` works but it may be slightly less efficient than a character class.*

Comment: Glad all I had was some metacharacter confusion. Dont think I would ever try to put an "|" inside "[]" I just like to avoid "()" whenever possible because they also are used to initialize special variables in Perl(and other languages) when something inside them matches.

Comment: I think a problem with this approach is that you "hardwire" the set of characters. If one day, one invents a character that is not matched by `.` (already the case: `\t`), one needs to *rewrite* all libraries that were based on such assumption...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `\t` is matched by `.`.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP Manual [page for Dot](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php) states that:

> If the PCRE_DOTALL option is set, then dots match newlines as well.

Answer (score 0):

An important thing is missing here. `[\s\S]` matches one character, whereas a newline can be a character sequence. (Windows uses two characters: `\r\n`.) Neither `.` (with [DOT_ALL](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier) nor `[\s\S]` will match the newline sequence. Best way to match any character or any newline is `(.|\R)`, "everything except a newline or a newline". `\R` matches `\n`, `\r` and `\r\n`.